# How to sort dictionary by decreasing integer value and then by decreasing string key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Given dictionary,

```
test_dict = {"A" : 1, "B" : 3, "C" : 2, "D" : 3, "E" : 2}
```

I want to sort the items by decreasing value and if the values are equal then by decreasing keys 
I tried :

```
res = {val[0] : val[1] for val in sorted(test_dict.items(), key = lambda x: (-x[1], -x[0]))}
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 12, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 12, in <lambda>
TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'str'
```

Comment: x[0] is an `str`, you can use `ord(x[0])` to get the ASCII value of it.

Comment: Fyi: Technically, a ` dict`  like the one you are building is not sorted even if you insert it in the sorted order. If it is sorted, that is more or less an implementation detail. (e.g python 3.7 [maintains order, apparently](https://softwaremaniacs.org/blog/2020/02/05/dicts-ordered/en/) but not all python 3 versions do)

Comment: for sorting backwards, there is the reverse keyword argument to ` sorted`

Comment: @lucidbrot Since 3.7 dicts being insertion order sorted is a language feature that needs to hold across all implementations.

Comment: I don't quite understand what is the point of ordering a dictionary. By default, dictionaries are ordered collections. That is, you are not going to access the elements of a dictionary in order, but you are going to do it by accesses via their keys.

Comment: @JoseManueldeFrutos maybe you need to iterate the keys in sorted order, or maybe you need to know which key was inserted last.

Comment: @timgeb You're right (for new enough versions of python) but it still feels dirty to me. I have now asked [whether relying on it is good practise](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/436092/is-it-good-practise-to-rely-on-the-insertion-order-of-python-dicts) hoping to get some insight on this.

Answer (score 3):

Your keys are strings, you can't make those negative. Try this instead:

```
res = {val[0] : val[1] for val in 
       sorted(test_dict.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]), reverse=True)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `dict(sorted(test_dict.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[::-1], reverse=True))`.